# Page scroll bottom when user try input anything: Safari issue

Tags: apex, javascript, jquery, ios, bootstrap

I am facing exactly this issue only difference is my scrolls down not top.

I try the workaround but can't get what changes I need to do. Can someone please guide me?

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T2oLAAS

Answer (score 3):

This hack worked well for me. Add the following JavaScript to your page:

```
<script> 
var ua=navigator.userAgent; 
if((ua.indexOf('Salesforce')!=-1)&&(ua.indexOf('iPhone')!=-1||ua.indexOf('iPad')!=-1)&&(ua.indexOf('OS/8')!=-1||ua.indexOf('OS 8')!=-1)&&(ua.indexOf('Safari')==-1)){ 
function IOS_SCROLL_BOOTSTRAP() { 
var children = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.body.children), 
placeholder = document.createElement('section'), 
fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(), 
styles, 
width, 
height; 
children.forEach(function(c){fragment.appendChild(c);}); 
placeholder.appendChild(fragment); 
styles = [ 
'width:100%;', 
'height:', (window.screen.height - 42), 'px;', 
'position: absolute; overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch' 
].join(''); 
placeholder.style.cssText = styles; 
document.body.appendChild(placeholder); 
} 
window.addEventListener('load', function (e) { 
IOS_SCROLL_BOOTSTRAP(); 
}); 
} 
</script>
```

If it did not work for you, it will be helpful to know what device, OS version and Safari version are you facing this issue on.

Comment: Not working for me. Shall I provide you my code?

Comment: Also where should I place this code? Just at the begining of the page?

Comment: Mine it's 10.2.1